# How can I self-invoke within a spring application given a URI?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I want to add support for user-created periodic tasks to my REST-ful web app.  I have a Spring Boot application that exposes data through a bunch of JSON returning controllers. What I'd like to do is have a "scheduler" controller that allows creation of "scheduled-tasks" that would consist of a schedule, an 'API call', and a target for where to send the result (some form of push to a third-party). Since the application already exposes a REST API the natural language for the user to express their scheduled 'API call' in is a URI. I'd like to be able to self-invoke this URI without having a to make a full-blown HTTP call against the system. Ideally I'd like also to do as much of the mapping work up front so that all I'm doing at the scheduled time is calling a `Supplier` that returns my result.

Anyone with an encyclopaedic knowledge of Spring have any ideas?